# Running Celery as root

Tags: linux, django, celery

I need to run my Django along with Celery as root for access reasons. It says I need to set C_FORCE_ROOT environment variable. How/where do I set the environment variable?

Comment: As far as I know, this is required only if the default serialization format `pickle` is being used.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can set it to true like this:

```
# export C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
```

Then make sure it is set as an env. variable

```
# echo $C_FORCE_ROOT
true
```

But make sure to make it permanent, as this will vanish with the next restart

Have fun :) !!

Comment: Even after setting the variable to "true" and printing for verification, the output after running is the following: `Running a worker with superuser privileges when the
worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!

If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
environment variable (but please think about this before you do).

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0`

Answer (score 20):

**1st solution** - Manually type command at terminal

```
$ export C_FORCE_ROOT='true'
```

---

**2nd solution** - Edit shell configuration

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc

    # add following line
    export C_FORCE_ROOT='true'

$ source ~/.bashrc
```

---

**3rd solution** - Edit `manage.py` of Django

```
import os 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('C_FORCE_ROOT', 'true')
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '{PATH TO SETTINGS FILE}')

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere so the python process picks it up by using [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ).

If your question is about how the environment variables work, please read [this tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_Variables).