# Purge unused containers kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm looking for the standard way to purge all unused container with a kubernetes on all nodes. Now I'm doing like this.

purge.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
#  Author:  Ali Said Omar
#  Created: '01/03/2016'
NODES=


function get_nodes(){
    # --label-columns=NAME does not filter on NAME column
    NODES=`kubectl get nodes --label-columns=NAME --no-headers | awk '{print $1}'`
}

function purge_on_nodes(){
    for NODE in $NODES
    do
        glcoud compute ssh $NODE -A "sudo docker ps -aq | xargs sudo docker rm"
    done
}

get_nodes
purge_on_nodes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this, because the system is meant to take care of it for you. Is there a particular reason that you need to do so? Or is the system malfunctioning in some way?

Comment: When my pods fails to start, I have need to purge all failed pods before trying again.

Comment: How have you determined that? Do you get errors when trying to create new ones? If so, what are the errors?

Comment: I finally found the root cause but the logs kubectl logs didn't show anything.

Comment: What was the root cause? Was it a bug in the system? Is there extra documentation or help text that we could provide? Any extra detail you can provide will help us improve things :)

Comment: My application was a celery app and won't start with root user. I updated the yaml to set the env as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346851/running-celery-as-root

Answer (score 0):

Use [Kubernetes Garbage collector](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/garbage-collection.html). There are settings (`minimum-container-ttl-duration`), which will help you to purge old containers.

Comment: Thanks, but still looking the way to force the garbage or use the option with yaml file (the document is not very clear on that)